# How to install multiple APKs in a single commit using Package Installer in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

**I am installing a single apk in the background using this function below**

```
fun install(context: Context, packageName: String, apkPath: String) {
        try {
            val packageInstaller = context.packageManager.packageInstaller
            // Prepare params for installing one APK file with MODE_FULL_INSTALL
            // We could use MODE_INHERIT_EXISTING to install multiple split APKs
            val params = PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL)
            params.setAppPackageName(packageName)
            // Get a PackageInstaller.Session for performing the actual update
            val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params)
            val session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)
            // Copy APK file bytes into OutputStream provided by install Session
            val out = session.openWrite(packageName, 0, -1)
            val fis = File(apkPath).inputStream()
            fis.copyTo(out)
            session.fsync(out)
            out.close()
            // The app gets killed after installation session commit
            session.commit(
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, sessionId,
                    Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"), 0).intentSender)
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.i(tag,e.toString())
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

**What I am trying to do:** I am trying to install multiple APKs in a single commit

Comment: Hey! Have you found anything that works here in this case?

Comment: @PrakharShukla ... Nop, It might be limitation. I ended up using a for loop to install all APK's one by one

Comment: A for loop screws up the installation dialog that asks for user's permission and only shows the last one unless that you wait for the user to accept or reject the permission for the previous one. Did you implement something like that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @PrakharShukla .... My Android was AOSP signed .... Android with AOSP signed will have system level privileges and it wont ask for user permission. I was able to implement this in my requirement